# How to build a Keras model with multidimensional input and output?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I am building a neural network to produce songs. I have one file which has all notes from one song and one line corresponds to one note:

```
0 0 0.05511 0.78740
0 0 0.07874 0.50393
0 0 0.71653 1
0 0 0.50393 0
.. .. .. ..
```

I want to give **10 first notes** to the neural network and I want it to give the **next note**, as the output, which has to be played after those 10 notes.

However I don't know how to build the first and the last layers (Dense, LSTM...) because I have:

1. an **input of 10x4 dimension** (4 columns and 10 lines).
2. an **output of 1x4 dimension** (1 line and 4 columns).

This is the beginning of my code (which doesn't read correctly my data):

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu',input_shape = (10,4)))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='relu'))
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a sequence forecasting problem which is best solved with recurrent or long short-term memory networks.

Following can be a good starter:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, Dropout
import numpy as np

#assuming all 4 columns correspond to 1 song
data_dim = 4
#so one song would be 10x4 2D array 
number_of_notes_per_song = 10
nsongs_train = 100
#tunable parameter
batch_size = 32
epochs = 5

# I generated dummy data, but you have your own...
x_train = np.random.random((nsongs_train, number_of_notes_per_song, data_dim)).reshape(nsongs_train*number_of_notes_per_song,data_dim)

#this is a supervised learning problem, but your dataset has no labels..
#we can use last note in each song as a label when training LSTM 
X = x_train[np.mod(np.arange(x_train.shape[0]),number_of_notes_per_song)!=0].reshape(nsongs_train,number_of_notes_per_song-1,data_dim)
y = x_train[::number_of_notes_per_song].reshape(nsongs_train,data_dim) 

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(32, input_shape=(number_of_notes_per_song-1, data_dim),return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(64))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(data_dim, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')

model.fit(X,y,batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs)

#predict on unseen data, expects tensors of shape (None, number_of_notes_per_song-1, data_dim)
model.predict(...)
```

Note, that this is a supervised machine learning problem, but your dataset has no labels. We can go around this by using the last note in each song as a label. This effectively reduces the sequence length by 1 note.

Note also, that if your song had hundreds of notes, it would be best to feed them to LSTM in sub-sequences, not resetting states until the end of the song. [Here](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-use-stateful-rnns) is an example of stateful training with Keras.

If need to forecast entire songs (rather than just a next character), you'd need to set `return_sequences=True` in all `LSTM` layers and use `TimeDistributed` dense layer at the output.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It helped me a lot. I did that and it worked. However how can I modify this program in order to read one file one by one so that the NN learns many songs and not just one? Because one file is just one song which has thousands of notes. So I would like to know what should be the shape of the input and output data taking account that I have many songs with thousands of notes? Thanks.